# Duplicate post on publish

Tags: publish

When I publish a post on wordpress Post is duplicated in the database.
One post with post status 'publish' and another with 'inherit'.
One post with comment status and ping status 'open' another with 'closed'.
One post with post type 'publish' and another with 'revision'.

But the blog showing only one post for each post.
What is the reason for this?.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behaviour of WordPress if you have attachments in your post and revision enable for your site.

When an attachment is added to a post, the attachment post_status is inherit of the parent post, and the logic is that the ping status is set to closed.

When revisions are enable, a copy of the post is created but not available in the post listing.

You can easily disable revision in the wp-config.php if you don't need them. See how to disable revision [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions)

Hope my answer helps you to understand that everything is going fine in what you say.

Comment: If you have a lot of post revisions in your database there are also plugins that can erase the drafts/revisions for you.